# How to implement a generic DAO using only java and jdbc (no ORM) for basic crud operations?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, crud, dao

I need any good DAO example with abstract classess and interfaces for basic CRUD operations, I searched for answers but most of them are examples with hibernate or other orm framework. Let say I have for example 2 model classes such as Employee and Job, I need an answer with generics.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

1. Use spring data repositories, which internally uses JPA (ORM) but exposes clean CRUD APIs. Implementation auto-generated.
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories
2. Create your own DAO interfaces and have your own simple jdbc
   implementation. Might take some help from spring jdbc utilities.
3. Use something like mybatis. It is a jdbc wrapper, not ORM.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I will evaluate the resources you have mentioned.